# Why I needs put * in Value of Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Sorry if it's stupid question: Before use Spring MVC worked with no problems (without *). Idk why I needs the *. The code works fine but if `getPlanilha` have the same `RequestMethod` and `Consumes` will execute `create` Method? Caused by the * since both will have the same value (`/planilha/anything`)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/planilha/*", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public String create(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestBody String jsonStr) {

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/planilha/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getPlanilha(@PathVariable("id") String id) {

}
```

Comment: I think I don't get the issue here, your previous mapping was to /planilha and you changed it to /planilha/** ? You should keep it that way, there is no need to use the wild card there

Comment: Don't works with "/planilha" (i have no idea why), I need change for "/planilha/*"

Comment: How does your servlet-mapping looks in your web.xml?